# Telnet stuck on "connecting"

Tags: windows-7, telnet

I am trying to telnet a port at a client's location. It shows `connecting....` for a long time but doesn't outputs any error message. The port is opened and other vendors are able to telnet the same port.
What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

here are some reasons..

- is your network connection ok, can you connect elsewhere?
- check for typos in hostname and port
- were you able to connect before from the same machine to the same machine?
- did something in between change (different network, provider, firewall)?
- is there a firewall on the machine where you want to connect to? maybe it restricts the
  clients.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a connection from the telnet port `Microsoft Telnet> open <destination> <port>` [enter] **results in connection hang**

Typing everything directly from the C prompt: `C:\TELNET <DESTINATION> <PORT>` 
[enter] **results in a blank screen** signifying the connection was successful.

Press **Ctrl + ]** to get back to Microsoft Telnet> then type `QUIT` to return to `C:\`

---

**NOTE:** I just learned this, and I have not researched it further at this point, so I can't tell you the 'WHY' behind why it works only that it does. Understanding why is just as important as knowing how, so if anyone can explain that portion than just include my half with your half and we'll use that as the correct answer.

Comment: Almost a year later I have the same question as the OP and Google brought me here. I tried to upvoted this solution and find out I can't because I wrote it lol.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experience but later figured out (with the help of a colleague) that it is just the Microsoft Telnet Screen printing issue;

Steps:

- Launch: *Microsft Telnet*
- Write: open IP PORT (e.g. open localhost 12344)
- You'll notice that cursor has reached to the top left of the    window signifying that **you can type your next command from
  there.**